# BLAS setup in R on macOS

Tags: r, macos, blas, intel-mkl

I am quite new to BLAS and Lapack setup. Executing

```
sessioninfo()
```

always returns

```
Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
```

I was wondering how `BLAS` can be called? Because I see many forks' default matrix products have both `BLAS` and `LAPACK`.

Also, how `Intel MKI` can be called? I have installed it on my macOS, but still wonder how to use it.

Also, my `R` is `4.0.5` and `macOS` is `macOS Big Sur 11.2.3`

Comment: See the R Mac FAQ: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#Which-BLAS-is-used-and-how-can-it-be-changed_003f To use MKL on your mac I think you'll have to compile R from source with the correct configuration. (https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/using-intel-mkl-with-r.html)

Comment: Thanks. The first FAQ is for changing BLAS. My problem is that BLAS does not show up.

Comment: How did you install R initially?

Comment: I downloaed the file ```R-4.0.5.pkg``` from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/

Comment: Are you using RStudio?  Try running R in the terminal.  Sometimes RStudio's startup environment interferes with sessionInfo/extSoftVersion BLAS detection.

Comment: @PNMNS yes, indeed, it seems RStudio interferes with the paths in R: In R terminal BLAS is found, but not in RStudio. How to fix???

Answer (score -2):

Please follow the below instructions, to build R with default BLAS, LAPACK using gnu compiler chain.

$ tar -xzvf R-4.0.5.tar.gz

$ cd R-4.0.5

$ ./configure

(or $./configure --with-readline=no --with-x=no if package readline and X11 is not installed)

$make

(not $ make install, so, we do not pollute system directory)

$ ldd bin/exec/R

(To make sure it will link libRblas.so although it may show that libRblas.so => not found)

For developers who have installed R, please locate the path of libRblas.so and
libRlapack.so (or libR.so), for example, $cd /usr/local/lib64/R

$ cd lib

$ mv libRblas.so libRblas.so.keep

$ln –s $(MKLROOT)/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_rt.so libRblas.so

The same way, you can replace the LAPACK libRlapack.so library too

($mv libRlapack.so libRlapack.so.keep
$ln –s $(MKLROOT)/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_rt.so libRlapack.so)

If you have prebuilt R with libR.so, replace it with
$(MKLROOT)/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_rt.so

Also you can go through the below links

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/quick-linking-intel-mkl-blas-lapack-to-r.html

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/using-intel-mkl-with-r.html

Comment: OP asked for Mac OS X instructions; linux shared objects don't apply (along with general paths to BLAS libs)